# pandas cumulative weighted average

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
 df :
   val       wt  
1  100       2
2  300       3
3  200       5

required df :

   val       wt  cum_wt_avg
1  100       2     100
2  300       3     220
3  200       5     210
```

formula :

> cum_wt_avg [i] =   cum_sum(val*wt)[i] / cum_sum(weight)[i]

Is there any easy way to do it in pandas or numpy to do this ? 
 Something like this

```
 df["cum_wt_avg"] = pd.cum_mean(value=df.val, weight=df.wt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in pandas best avoid loops.

So first multiple columns by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html), get [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and divide by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)ed column `wt`:

```
df["cum_wt_avg"] = df['val'].mul(df['wt']).cumsum().div(df['wt'].cumsum())
print (df)
   val  wt  cum_wt_avg
1  100   2       100.0
2  300   3       220.0
3  200   5       210.0
```

For improve performance use `numpy` with [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = df['val'].values
b = df['wt'].values
df["cum_wt_avg"] = np.cumsum(a * b) / np.cumsum(b)
```

**Timings**:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

#jpp solution
@jit(nopython=True)
def cum_wavg(arr, res):
    return np.cumsum(arr[:, 0] * arr[:, 1])/ np.cumsum(arr[:, 1])

def jez1(df):
    a = df['val'].values
    b = df['wt'].values
    return np.cumsum(a * b) / np.cumsum(b)

print (jez1(df))

In [184]: %timeit cum_wavg(df.values, res=np.zeros(len(df.index)))
65.5 µs ± 27.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [185]: %timeit df['val'].mul(df['wt']).cumsum().div(df['wt'].cumsum())
362 µs ± 6.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [186]: %timeit (jez1(df))
63.8 µs ± 491 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes. That will work. But I was searching for a compact function

Comment: @ManiBharathy - I search it, but seems in pandas and numpy is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

def cum_wavg(arr):
    return [np.average(arr[:i+1, 0], weights=arr[:i+1, 1]) for i in range(arr.shape[0])]

df['cum_wavg'] = cum_wavg(df.values)
```

For better performance, you can use `numba`:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

@jit(nopython=True)
def cum_wavg(arr, res):
    return np.cumsum(arr[:, 0] * arr[:, 1])/ np.cumsum(arr[:, 1])

%timeit cum_wavg(df.values, res=np.zeros(len(df.index)))           # 92.9 µs
%timeit df['val'].mul(df['wt']).cumsum().div(df['wt'].cumsum())    # 549 µs
```

Comment: Thanks for the jit. Will try using it.